# Difference between DELETE and DELETE FROM in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-delete

Is there one?  I am researching some stored procedures, and in one place I found the following line:

```
DELETE BI_Appointments
WHERE VisitType != (
    SELECT TOP 1 CheckupType
    FROM BI_Settings
    WHERE DoctorName = @DoctorName)
```

Would that do the same thing as:

```
DELETE FROM BI_Appointments
WHERE VisitType != (
    SELECT TOP 1 CheckupType
    FROM BI_Settings
    WHERE DoctorName = @DoctorName)
```

Or is it a syntax error, or something entirely different?

Comment: SQL Server: They do the same thing when only one table is referenced. Type "tsql delete" into Google to find out more...

Comment: Please Read [This][1] SO Thread for more detail.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484250/in-sql-syntax-is-from-in-delete-from-optional-if-you-plan-to-use-where

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assuming this is T-SQL or MS SQL Server, there is no difference and the statements are identical.  The first `FROM` keyword is syntactically optional in a `DELETE` statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql

The keyword is optional for two reasons.

First, the standard requires the `FROM` keyword in the clause, so it would have to be there for standards compliance.

Second, although the keyword is redundant, that's probably not why it's optional. I believe that it's because SQL Server allows you to specify a `JOIN` in the `DELETE` statement, and making the first `FROM` mandatory makes it awkward.

For example, here's a normal delete:

```
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE ID = @value
```

And that can be shortened to:

```
DELETE Employee WHERE ID = @value
```

And SQL Server allows you to delete based on another table with a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE Employee
FROM Employee
    JOIN Site
       ON Employee.SiteID = Site.ID
WHERE Site.Status = 'Closed'
```

If the first `FROM` keyword were not optional, the query above would need to look like this:

```
DELETE FROM Employee
FROM Employee
    JOIN Site
       ON Employee.SiteID = Site.ID
WHERE Site.Status = 'Closed'
```

This above query is perfectly valid and does execute, but it's a very awkward query to read. It's hard to tell that it's a single query. It looks like two got mashed together because of the "duplicate" `FROM` clauses.

Side note: Your example subqueries are potentially non-deterministic since there is no `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: If it's optional, why does it exist at all?

Comment: @JoeM That's how the ANSI SQL standard defines the query syntax.  It's there for standard language syntax compliance.

Answer (score 5):

Hi friends there is no difference between delete and delete from in oracle database it is optional, but this is standard to write code like this
`DELETE FROM table [ WHERE condition ]` 
this is sql-92 standard. always develop your code in the standard way.