# SQL server: difference between DELETE <Table> and DELETE from <Table>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

SQL server: 

Difference between :

```
Delete tblxyz where id=6
```

and :

```
Delete from tblxyz  where id=6
```

Is their any difference between above queries ?

Comment: no.............

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: I never know that first syntax will work

Comment: Keep the `FROM` keyword, as ANSI SQL and all (?) other products require it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between DELETE and DELETE FROM in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336807/difference-between-delete-and-delete-from-in-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]There is no difference if you see the execution plan both generates delete scripts as below

```
DELETE [testtable]  WHERE [numbers]=@1
```

Comment: Although the two are equivalent, testing an execution plan on a single query only shows that those two queries on a particular system produce the same plan.  It says nothing general about the syntax itself.

Comment: Note that ANSI SQL requires the `FROM` keyword. I.e. it's good programming practice keeping it, as it makes the code more portable. (And easier to read, at least for less MS SQL Server experienced users.)

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct difference between the two statements
(except that I find the "DELETE FROM" easier to read and understand)

note that ANSI does require the "FROM" keyword as stated by jarlh

see also 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: Note that ANSI SQL requires the `FROM` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN the word "from" is optional. The default is not to use:

> FROM
>
> and the target table_or_view_name, or rowset_function_limited.An optional keyword that can be used between the DELETE keyword

However in MS Access (or may be some other databases) you may delete a row using `delete *` command, so you have to use **from**:

```
delete * from phoneBook where....
```

Comment: There is no such thing as deleting a column not a row. You can update a column to null or drop a column but not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in your delete.

However, the `FROM` clause is a fully functional from clause, so you can use it with `JOIN`.  For instance:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from t
          group by grp
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.minid;
```

This would delete the record with the minimum id for each `grp` value.  The alias after the `delete` is needed to specify which table to delete from (although in this case, deleting from an aggregation result is not allowed).

Note:  This query is for illustrative purposes.  There is nothing wrong with the query, but it is not how I would actually write such a query in SQL Server.

Comment: That is a different `FROM`. The grammar supports two. The one they are asking about is the first one. That would be `DELETE FROM t` in your example code. The second one is ` FROM table_source ` the `FROM` is not optional in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The from Clause is optional..Below is stripped down version of Syntax..

DELETE
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]
    [ FROM ]
    { { table_alias

> FROM
>   An optional keyword that can be used between the DELETE keyword and the target table_or_view_name, or rowset_function_limited.